Clarification on Memory Allocation Direction: Data Section vs. Stack
I'm a bit confused about the direction of memory allocation in different memory segments in x86_64 architecture. When I initialize variables in the data section, they seem to be allocated in increasing memory addresses, but when I use the stack, values are pushed onto it in decreasing memory addresses. Could someone please clarify why there's this apparent discrepancy? Is it a consistent convention across different systems, or are there variations based on the compiler or system settings? I want to understand the underlying principles better.

Having the stack grow downward is an optimal strategy for using all the "available memory" when you don't know how big the data will be. As the data and the stack grow closer, they'll only meet if there's no more room left. You place the data at the first available address and the stack at the latest. If they both grew in the same direction you'd have to leave an arbitrary gap between them, but how big this gap should be? Most of the time you will have unused data/stack space when running out of (respectively) stack/data space.

Another reason for having the stack grow down is that this way, all stack slots have a positive offset from the stack pointer.  For x86 it's not super relevant, but on other architectures this allows the CPU designer to get away with not supporting negative indices in indexed addressing modes.
